# having trouble configuring mysql on php in windows xp

Tags: mysql, windows, php

I've been trying hard to get this simple configuration problem resolved.  All I want is to enable mysql so it could work with my php.  In my environment, I have PHP 5.2/IIS 5.0/MySQL 5.0 configured on my Windows XP machine, and all setup.  From what I heard from numerous sources of technical advice, the simple thing to enable MySQL is to uncomment these lines from php.ini file.

**extension=php_mysql.dll

extension=php_mysqli.dll**

and modify the **extension_dir**

**extension_dir = "c:\php\ext"**

But after all that, it's still not working.

I went on investigating the cause of the issue by running *phpinfo()* and I realised mysql functions is not enabled at all.  (Bizarre...) Then I open up command prompt, typed **php -m** and confirmed that mysql functions were enabled.

Finally, one interesting discovery I found is that I typed **php -i** and found these couple of lines.

**Configuration File (php.ini) Path => C:\WINDOWS

Loaded Configuration File => C:\php\php.ini**

But under *phpinfo()*, it shows the following:

**Configuration File (php.ini) Path C:\WINDOWS

Loaded Configuration File   (none)**

Loaded Configuration File from *phpinfo()* is missing!  Why??  How did it end up here?

Anyone got any ideas?

PS: I've setup my environment variable PATH to point to C:\php\ folder so that's working fine.

Comment: http://www.wimpserver.com/articles.php maybe this helps

Comment: Copy libmysql.dll to the system folder. It works with CLI php because it is in the folder with php.exe. Copy php.ini also.

Comment: Sorry Cheery.  I tried that before.  Still doesn't work.  When trying to access the page.  It comes up saying "No input file specified", unless you know another solution to this problem?

Comment: Cheery - never mind.  I've fixed it.  After following your copy and paste to system32 folder solution, I googled the "no input file error" for a solution.  I had to uncomment this line 

doc_root = c:\inetpub\wwwroot

in the php.ini file now it works okay.

Despite this fix, I'm still no convinced this is the solution I really want since the main point behind with environment system variable was to tell Windows XP I got my own PATH variable to pic ie C:\php not C:\Windows\system32 folder.  And XP just ignored it altogether.

This is not supposed to happen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guy's got the answer what I'm lookin for.

http://www.peterguy.com/php/install_IIS6.html